# Strange behaviour when using Codeception with Laravel-Elixir

Tags: laravel, codeception, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

Been experimenting with Laravel-Elixir (within a Laravel 5 project) and Codeception. I have a complete fresh and unaltered Laravel 5 project, added Elixir (and all necessary tools) to that. And it is a great tool, let me say that first!
After that I installed Codeception and added the codeception extension to Elixir. All still fine. After that I added a very basic Codeception test like so:

```
<?php
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('perform actions and see result');
$I->amOnPage("/");
$I->see('arrived');
?>
```

Strange thing now is that if I run '*codecept run*' I get the expected report of Codeception telling me one test is executed and is OK.
But if I run '*gulp*' all Elixir-tasks are executed as expected but I get the message that my codeception tests failed.

Anybody an explanation for this? Apart from some necessary configuration (like the correct path to my server in the codeception configuration) I chnaged nothing to the basic installations out of the box.

Thanks,

Edwin